# How to apply rule based patch for 'shopsServiceUrl' in Y.Commerce.Engine?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

While using azure appservice deployment slots the urls for the sites (which ever has the slot) change and on swap it should not get swapped.
In Sitecore commerce - we have Y.Commerce.Engine we have url to shops and ops hardcoded

**<commerceEngineConfiguration type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.CommerceEngineConfiguration, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect">
      <shopsServiceUrl>https://commerceauthoring.sc.com/api/</shopsServiceUrl>

</commerceEngineConfiguration>**

The url should remain same upon swap. We have defined rule on the azure configuration as in below .
based on this config I should be able to change the url dynalically with patch config.
How can we achieve this? How the Patch config will look like?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: need more info.. You want the commerce engine url to be same on deployment slot and main slot? It should be automatic if you have role based configs.

Comment: Hi Kautilya, I need 2 different urls for shop and also we have commerce engine specific to slot. ex: for staging: the <shopsServiceUrl>  should be https://commerceauthoring.sc.com-staging/api/  and for Production it should be https://commerceauthoring.sc.com/api/  without staging keyword.

Comment: so u need slot specific configs. You can do that by adding a new config setting called "Slot", add it in the web.config just like role and then reference it in the sitecore config files just like role. I hope your web.config is not overwritten by deployments.

Comment: web.config is not part of deployment. But when you do swap of slots in azure  everything (including configs) will be swaped- for more info on what exactly happen on swap please go through the link: https://learnwithshahriar.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/azure-website-101-swapping/

Comment: @sc.kautilya- I understand what you said about slot specific configuration. But does that apply to Json files as well? My requirement is for .json file.